# Plotting a timestamp with django and matplotlib

Tags: python, django, csv, matplotlib, django-views

I'm having some trouble creating a view in django, I'm trying to make a web app which will read in from a csv and then display the plot, however the time axis I need to plot from the csv is not a float it is a string, then way I have it here I'm not sure how to plot this timestamp:

```
def showMe(request):
    fig = Figure()
    canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
    x, y = np.loadtxt('/Users/name/Desktop/garden_app/stored.csv', delimiter=',', dtype={'names': ('time','moisture'), 'formats': ('|S1', np.float)}, unpack=True)
    plt.plot(x, y, align='center', alpha=0.5, label='Name')
    plt.ylabel('moisture')
    plt.xlabel('time')
    plt.title('Moisture V. Time')
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(buf, format='png')
    plt.close(fig)
    response = HttpResponse(buf.getValue(), content_type = 'image/png')
    return response
```

The csv file I have looks like this:

```
moisture,time,pump,light,temperature
1023,2019-10-27 17:22:27.367391,running,5V,25 Celsius
1023,2019-10-27 17:22:30.402280,running,5V,25 Celsius

...
```

The "ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'time'" comes from the 'formats': ('|S1', np.float) on line 4, I'm just not sure how to change this where one is a number and the other is the timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you read the csv file with pandas, it does not require your data to be purely floats.

```
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/name/Desktop/garden_app/stored.csv', parse_dates=True, index_col='time', sep=",")
```

After reading you can pass the dataframe columns to matplotlib.